# Status Returned 200 but response body is blank

Tags: rest-api, rest, rest-service

I'm new to integration. I am going to generate an access token for the third-party application.

I tried to build following javascript request in sfdc.

But the response body is blank. I need to retrieve access token & other things to call specific endpoint in another class.Please let me know where i did wrong

I am searlize json string also while sending the body

They gave same code request sample in java format like below.

```
var result = {};
var application = "";
var vendor = "";
var businessunit = "";
var user = "";
var pass = "";
var authCode = window.btoa(application + "@" + vendor + ":" + businessunit);
$.ajax({
    "url": 'https://',
    "type": 'post',
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "dataType": 'json',
    "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'basic ' + authCode
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
    "grant_type": 'password',
    "username": user,
    "password" : pass,
    "scope": 'AdminApi AgentApi AuthenticationApi PatronApi RealTimeApi'
    }),
    "success": function (resp) {
        result.access_token = resp.access_token;
        result.token_type = resp.token_type;
        result.resource_server_base_uri = resp.resource_server_base_uri;
        result.expires_in = resp.expires_in;
        result.refresh_token = resp.refresh_token;
        result.scope = resp.scope;
        result.refresh_token_server_uri = resp.refresh_token_server_uri;
    },
    "error": function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed to retrieve token.\n" + XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' 
            + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
    }
});
```

My Apex class

```
    public class AuthCallout {
    public void basicAccessTokenGeneration() {
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint('https://');
     req.setMethod('POST');

     // Specify the required username and password to access the endpoint
     // As well as the header and header information

     String username = '';
     String password = '';
     String vendor   = '';
     String businessunit ='';
     String application ='';

     Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(application + '@' + vendor + ':' + businessunit);
     String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
     EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
     req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);


    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    

    gen.writeStartObject();      
    gen.writeStringField('grant_type ', 'password');
    gen.writeStringField('username', username);
    gen.writeStringField('password',password);
    gen.writeStringField('scope','');
    gen.writeEndObject();
    String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
    system.debug('DAta in '+str);
    system.debug('Data in gen'+jsonS);
    req.setBody(jsonS);
     // Create a new http object to send the request object
     // A response object is generated as a result of the request  

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     System.debug(res.getBody());
        System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(res.getBodyDocument());
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the response body which is receiving from third party?  As per your comment it's successfully sent your request to third party,  Can you check with admin of third party?

Comment: As per there documentation, they said you will get access token and other stuff like this result.access_token = resp.access_token;
        result.token_type = resp.token_type;
        result.resource_server_base_uri = resp.resource_server_base_uri;
        result.expires_in = resp.expires_in;
        result.refresh_token = resp.refresh_token;
        result.scope = resp.scope;
        result.refresh_token_server_uri = resp.refresh_token_server_uri

Comment: But i got response body is blank

Comment: Can you paste your response here?

Comment: Debug logs are blank Only it is displaying status code 200 and  status OK

Comment: You have to ask third party team.

Comment: Even if i give wrong credentials still i got same status code

Comment: Oh... You should check with you third party development team that whether your request is hitting their server or not so we can proceed further.

Comment: When i check from postman client it is working fine there but status is showing 409 Login failed. You must change your password.

Comment: So you are saying the problem in apex callout?

Comment: I think so.will you please look into the code and let me know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to get the response body with an access token. The error is the password of the client I'm using in above API call.

When I check from postman I got the status code as

> 409 Login failed. You must change your password.

Once I reset the password. Everything works smoothly